# Error importing module in Python inside a Docker container with a Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile, uwsgi

I am actually working on my final project to get my certificate and my role on it is Backend Developer, our Architecture is Microservices which uses containers so Docker, we chose languages like C#, Python and TypeScript for every single microservice of the web application.

I'm working in a microservice in Python using Flask, I was consulting on the internet and when using Flask as a backend framework uWSGI is used for production, so I'm trying to build a Docker image with the Flask app and the uWSGI ready for production; so my issue is that in my computer (not containerized service) the Flask app works pretty good, I have one file called `app.py` with a line that imports the database file like this `from Database import db as Database` and it works good.

The file `db.py` is in a folder called `Database`, its route is `Service/src/Database/db.py` and the app.py is in `Service/src/app.py`.

I'm using the image `tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask:latest` for the build and this is my Docker file

```
FROM tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask:latest

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requeriments.txt requeriments.txt

COPY . .

ENV SECRET=token_secret

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requeriments.txt
```

My issue is that when I build the image and run a container like this

> docker run -d -p 8000:80 -e APP_MODULE="src.app:app" myimage

It gets this error:

```
2023-03-28 22:29:29 [2023-03-29 03:29:29 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-03-28 22:29:29 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2023-03-28 22:29:29     worker.init_process()
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-03-28 22:29:29     self.load_wsgi()
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-03-28 22:29:29     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-03-28 22:29:29     self.callable = self.load()
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-03-28 22:29:29     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-03-28 22:29:29     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2023-03-28 22:29:29     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2023-03-28 22:29:29     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-03-28 22:29:29   File "/app/src/app.py", line 6, in <module>
2023-03-28 22:29:29     from Database import db as Database
2023-03-28 22:29:29 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Database'
2023-03-28 22:29:29 [2023-03-29 03:29:29 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
```

I've been try with Docker compose and a lot of ways to build and run the image with uWSGI incorporated for Flask but I get the same error every time.

I tried to build an image using Ubuntu and installing uWSGI and Python and configurate it, I tried to use another image like `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask` and also I used docker compose whit a docker-compose.yaml file like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    api:
        build: .
        working_dir: /app
        environment:
            - FLASK_APP=src/app.py
            - MONGODB_URI=mongo_connecton_string
            - SECRET=token_secret
        command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0

    webserver:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

And it works but it is not what I need.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Do you have a ```__init__.py``` in your Database dir?

Comment: Yes, I tried with it and without it, but it doen't work

Comment: I feel it's  a path related issue.  Is the ```Database``` directory stored in ```/app```?

Comment: yes, its path is /app/src/